# General Regression Neural Network (GRNN) how the sigma is updated ?

Tags: regression, neural-networks

General Regression Neural Network is a one-pass neural network. The spread of the data sigma is updated based on output error. But I did not quite understood how it is changed. Anyone knowledgeable about this neural network can answer this? Thanks.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18282872

http://easyneuralnetwork.blogspot.ca/2013/07/grnn-generalized-regression-neural.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GRNN uses lazy learning approach for training. It's a more complicated way to say that it doesn't require learning. During the training process it just stores training data and later uses it for predictions. Sigma is a fixed parameter that you need to define. Some of the source can refer to "sigma training" as a hyperparameter selection problem. Which means that you can try multiple sigma parameters and then you can validate performance with your validation data. Parameter that gives you the lowest error is the one that you want to use in your application.

If you are familiar with Python then you can check this example: https://github.com/itdxer/neupy/blob/master/examples/rbfn/grnn_params_selection.py